# Can a block-chain with embedded shared content stop cheating?

Tags: node.js, game-theory

I want to make a game where users create their content and embed it in a block-chain. For example, they have a small x,y grid. In the grid they place objects... After the grid is made they share it via block-chain with others. The other players then experience this content and try to pass it unfairly. I feel like there is a way in the block chain to stop them via agreement or algorithm?
Is this possible?

Comment: Blockchains are most useful when you don't have/trust a central authority to adjudicate matters. But with games, there's almost always a central authority the players have to trust: the game's creators. So you might not need this kind of decentralization. Can you explain why you want to use a blockchain in this scenario?

Comment: I was interested if blockchain technology could replace an authoritative server. Would probably go this direction: "Option 2.1: People own tiles, and the game is instantiated."

Comment: How do players find other players' machines to negotiate blockchains or other claims with, in the absence of a central server?

Comment: That's a good point, there would need to be contact with a server. If the blockchain could take some of that work off the server, reducing server requests would save money and players could also play offline. I need to think it through some more, I'll update within the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Centralized Game

If are going to control the servers of the game. You do not need a decentralized solution such as block-chain. In fact, you will not even need cryptography (beyond what is necessary for proper user authentication) to maintain it.

Considering that you tag a server side technology (node.js), I suspect you intend to deploy servers. Thus, you will be making a centralized game. If that is the case, then you do not need block-chain.

**Note**: Your game can still be P2P, offline, or whatever. When I say decentralized, I am not referring to who hosts the game, but who creates the content of the game.

Before you consider a decentralized game. Consider that you could make a game that includes a map editor, and then people can create their own maps, and perhaps mail them to their friends or share them on some website.

---

### Decentralized Game

So, do you want a decentralized game? *One in which people can create content for it, and it is considered official and part of the core game without the need of a central authority serving, reviewing or approving?*

Then, perhaps, block-chains can help you.

I will go over how block-chains work and cryptocurrencies work, without going into much detail, and then come back to your game.

### How do the block-chains work?

The block-chain has blocks. These are published over Internet for anybody to download.

Each block in the block-chain points to the previous block, which allows to organize the blocks chronologically (hence, "chain"). In addition, each block has a body (some data being stored, will come back to this) and a proof of work based on the hash of the rest of data of block (including the reference to the previous block) and a difficulty parameter.

A notable characteristic of the block-chain system is that the longest chain is considered the valid one. If, temporally, there are multiple branches of the block-chain (that happens when you have various blocks pointing back to the same previous block) that are the same length, eventually one will come ahead and considered the official one.

In fact, that is how the block-chain can enforce a contract. Assuming the rules to verify a contract are encoded in the software that creates the blocks, the nodes will be able to read the body of the blocks and decide if they are ok according to those rules. If the majority agrees that a block is invalid, then any branch that includes that block will die out as the nodes choose to continue adding blocks only to valid branches, making them longer.

You could try to create a rogue node with modified software that considers valid whatever crazy transaction you want to allow. However, the collective of the others nodes will produce blocks faster than your node. As a result, your branch will lag behind, and nobody will consider it valid (except, perhaps, you).

### How cryptocurrencies work?

For cryptocurrencies, the body is a public ledger. That is, a list of transactions. For example something similar to "the wallet x pays the wallet y, z amount". *Of course, we need to figure out a binary format for what we will be storing in the block-chain.*

To ensure that I cannot just put that “scranley” pays seven quadrillion coins to “theraot” and publish it somewhere in the ledger, the transaction will require a digital signature with the key of the source wallet. This allows the nodes to verify that the person who pays authorized it (unless somebody stole the key to your wallet).

The nodes will also make sure that nobody pays more than they have. How do they know how much do you have? Well, it is in the ledger.

In cryptocurrencies, the incentive to contribute blocks (that is, to compile the data, do the proof of work and publish it to the rest of the network) is to be able to earn some cryptocurrency as a reward for providing that service. We call it “mining”.

Now, the first way miners earn cryptocurrency is by adding a transaction that pays the miner some amount. With the particularity that they are being in an special transaction that does not come from any wallet. The network can set a maximum amount the miners can get by these means by simply ignoring any blocks that go beyond the maximum.

The second way miners earn cryptocurrency is by having people paying an extra ammount. When this happens the miner takes it as a transaction fee. Doing this the person making payments can provide an incentive for miners to include their transactions into the block.

**Note**: What I have said above about miners applies to miner pools. The miner pool will build blocks and give them to the miners in the pool to complete their proof of work. That allows the pool to distribute the work across various miners. In addition, of course, the pool will add the payments to the miners in the blocks it builds (according to whatever payment policy the pool has).

---

### How to build the game?

For the premise of the game, I will say that there are tiles, and each tile has…

> a small x,y grid. In the grid they place objects... After the grid is made they share it via block-chain with others

This poses the problem of ownership: Who has the right to public the contents of a particular tile or set of tiles?

**Option 1: Nobody owns the land**

*Option 1.1: Nobody own the land, and the game is instantiated.*

In this scenario, somebody updates the contents of a tile, and then a few moments later somebody overwrites what the first person did. There is no real value. Skip.

---

*Option 1.2: Nobody owns the land, but the block-chain is the game.*

I suppose you could build a game around this concept if you have some strong contracts about what updates are valid.

For instance, I can imagine a turn based strategy game where you put the actions you do on your turn to the block chain, and the nodes verify that:

- You only move on your turn.
- You only move your units, and they move only as much as it is valid.
- You do not multiply your units without paying resources.
- Etc.

It would be impossible to have a fog of war or to keep moves secret.
Now, considering that each turn requires a proof of work, the game would be slow. However, it could be interesting for a reasonable number people to play a match, and have then make alliances and plans over email or social media… and some player backstabs them allies, etc…

*For abstract, I think this could be a gimmicky way to play Diplomacy.*

I won't expect such game to be very popular. But, that is just my opinion.

**Option 2:  People own tiles**

*Option 2.1: People own tiles, and the game is instantiated.*

In this case, you can only specify the contents of a tile that you own. The nodes would hold the contract that you can only update your tile.

Then, how do you earn/buy a tile? Short answer: currency.

A miner completes a block; allow them to take currency. You can make the tile the currency, or allow to buy tiles using the currency. Aside from that, the body includes these kinds of operations are:

- Wallet x gives the tile z to the wallet y.
- Wallet x updates the contents of the tile z.

Now, if I want to get a tile, I need to:

- Buy it from somebody who owns it - for whatever currency, goods or services they want from it - and thus, these tiles would have some real world value.
- Contribute to the mining process and earn it that way.

If you can manage to make owning tiles intrinsically rewarding by gameplay, then the values of these tiles would never fall below the utility of the game. *Using the word utility here in a very loose sense.*

Now, sure, making your own maps and having other people play them can be intrinsically rewarding. However, I am talking about owning these tiles.

As I said at the start of the answer, you could make a game that includes a map editor, and then people can create their own maps, and share them. Why not do that? **What is the value of owning a tile?**

If you want my suggestion, I would say that the value is creating a large map where everybody owns a chunk. Then the value not only comes from creating and sharing, and does not only comes from saying “I made this”, it also comes from being a part of something bigger, and furthermore… it comes from the particular position of a tile respect to the others. I can imagine people organizing themselves to acquire adjacent tiles to make massive projects (assuming the game is good).

*And some of the massive projects will be depictions of human genitalia, because Internet.*

Do not forget to make the game engaging. You can make a bad game, despite – or perhaps because of – the block-chain.

---

*Option 2.2: People own the tiles, and the block-chain is the game.*

In this case, what you put on the tiles needs to have some synergy with what is in the other tiles. Moreover, you need to introduce other resources that players can exchange aside from the tiles themselves (and whatever main currency you have).

I would suggest making the game cooperative – or at least partially cooperative – such that I set up agreements with my neighbors, and trade with them. For example, I could put a mine in my tile, and doing so would allow me expend ten gold (*that is a block added to the block-chain*). And then I can give five gold to my neighbor in exchange for one diamond (*that is a block added to the block-chain*). Then, expending the diamond may allow me to build something else… etc. In addition, the nodes block-chain network would verify that I do not cheat in any of these turns.

Furthermore, this can be a meta-game for the instantiated version. Consider, for example, that the game is a city simulator, and it mainly played offline. When you earn your tile, it grants you x money that you expend in the game (offline). Then you update your city to the block-chain after your play session (or when you run out resources), and depending on what you build (which the nodes can verify it matches the resources you had) you earn more resources. Furthermore, you could make agreements with your neighbors via the blockchain. And so on…

---

### Final note

*Oh, what if each tile is a dungeon and we pay people some currency when they beat it?*

Well, for that to work. The network needs to be able to verify that you did actually beat it. And they are not taking your claim of it.

We could consider publishing your steps to beat it, that way the network can verify if those steps will in fact lead to the dungeon being completed. And then do a proof of work overthat.

However, that means that it is easier to have a software beat the dungeon and claim the currency. Now, either people want the currency more than playing the game. In which case, the game fails. people rather play the game and to get the currency. In which case this reward system is pointless.

However, I am not saying that a game where people build dungeons and put them in the block-chain for others to play cannot work… but you still need to solve the problem of why it is valuable to own tiles in the block chain (instead of just having a map editor and a way to share maps with other people).

Comment: Yes, the game has a map editor included.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, using block chain is probably overkill, but yes. Any decent modern encryption method applied to shared content, whilst not preventing outright tampering, would render tampered data useless (as it wouldn't decrypt properly).

A simpler method is to take your example grid, break it into "labelled" chunks, and apply something simple like SHA256 to each chunk, if you really feel the need to encrypt.

Then(and this is the weak part of encryption) figure out a secure way to share the encryption key with other users. You could embed it into your source code, but if you are using javascript it might not be very secure.

Once you have a mechanism for sharing keys and encrypted data, in theory, the shared content should be secure from tampering. In practice, however, if someone is determined enough, they'll manage it.